# How to upload files Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

how to add files to Laravel Storage and save name to DB

i can add one by one but multiple files. i' stuck please help me

**This is my View.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('name', 'Файлаа энд хуулна уу') !!}
{!! Form::file('attachments[]', ['roles' => 'form', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
{!! Form::token() !!}
</div>
{!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])  !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**This is my Controller**

```
public function handleUpload(Request $request)
{
     if (Auth::check()){
        $files = $request->file('attachments');
        $allowedFileTypes = config('app.allowedFileTypes');
        $maxFileSize = config('app.maxFileSize');
        $rules = ['file' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize];
        $this->validate($request,$rules);
        $fileName = now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
        $userName = Auth::user()->name;
        $division = $request->input('division');
        $destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$division.'/'.$userName.'/'.$fileName;
         foreach ($files as $file) {
        $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath,file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
         }
        if($uploaded){
            Project::create([
                'description' => $request->input('description'),
                'division' => $request->input('division'),
                'who' => $request->input('who'),
                'whom' => $request->input('whom'),
                'content' => $request->input('content'),
                'filename' => $division.'/'.$userName.'/'.$fileName
            ]);
        }
    return redirect()->to('/projects/');
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are validating wrong input parameter.

```
$rules = ['file' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize];
```

Change to -

```
$rules = ['attachments.*' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize];
```

I have make a whole change according to your code. Try this-

```
    $files = $request->file('attachments');
    $allowedFileTypes = config('app.allowedFileTypes');
    $maxFileSize = config('app.maxFileSize');
    $rules = ['attachments.*' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize];
    $this->validate($request,$rules);
    $userName = Auth::user()->name;
    $division = $request->input('division');
    $destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$division.'/'.$userName.'/';
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $fileName = now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
        $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath.$fileName.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(),file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
    }
```

Comment: Sir its giving me `The attachments must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, bmp, png, pdf`

Comment: check your validation rules probably `$allowedFileTypes` this variable causing you this

Comment: `allowedFileTypes' => 'jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,pdf`

Comment: then you need to upload files with this extension

Comment: `$extension = $request->file->extension();` like this how to upload with that? like this? `$uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath,file_get_contents($file->getRealPath(), $extension));` ?

Comment: `$fileName = now()->format('Y-m-d-H i-s').$file>getClientOriginalExtension();` add this line inside for loop

Comment: `The file field is required`

Comment: im sorry my mistake i didnt change into  attachments

Comment: im sorry sir :( its not working same error? `The attachments must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, bmp, png, pdf.`

Comment: maybe can i change my mimes?

Comment: `$rules = ['attachments[]' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize];`

Comment: that extensions is working in 1 file. on files its not working as well i guess

Comment: `The attachments[] field is required.` im so confused :O

Comment: `{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/handleUpload' , 'files' => true)) !!}`

Comment: it works it works HELL YEA Thank you sir thank you bless you but can u explain this code for me ?

Comment: `attachments.*` use for validating array input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162960/discussion-between---and-sohel0415).